# I want to show alert dialog for user phone number on fb login button click before redirecting to login page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I want to validate the user phone number first on fb login button click. 
The alert dialog shows but within seconds it's redirected to callback function. How can I handle this so that I can validate user phone number and redirect to fb login page else cancel the request.

```
 _fbloginbutton.setOnClickListener(this);



        //Callback registration
        _fbloginbutton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
```

---

Handling the click listener and want to take input using showAlertdialog() function

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                ShowAlertdialog();
                signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.fb_login_button:
                ShowAlertdialog();
                break;
```